# Oracle-Apex: Dynamically redirecting from login button

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-20.1

**The scenario**

I have implemented social authentication similarly to described by Dimitri Gielisin hist post "Facebook, Google and Custom Authentication in the same Oracle APEX 18.1 app" (http://dgielis.blogspot.com/2018/06/facebook-google-and-custom.html)

The pertinent point is that there is a button which has the request 'APEX_AUTHENICATION=FACEBOOK' which logs the user in and also hard codes the page that the user is taken to.

[image]

It works great. (However if I have a login menu item which directs back to the same page - the user name isn't updated on the page.)

**The Issue**

Default behaviour is for apex to redirect users to the login page when they attempt to access a page which is not publicly available.  After logging in the user is taken to the page hard coded page in the button (except for modal dialogues which just produce an invalid session error).

I'd love it if they could sign in and then continue to the page they need to go to. Is there some not extremely cumbersome ways of doing that? I thought of trying to saving the page number I want the user to go to into an application item and then having the button redirecting based on the application item- but while I was saving the page number the dynamic redirect in the button is not working...and I feel like I'm fighting the apex framework...

Is there a better way? If not can a button reference an item for the page number? I was trying &APP_ITEM. but that didn't seem to work...
[image]

(I"m using Apex 20.1)

Comment: Hello Emo, check the "deep linking" attribute for your app (Application Properties > Security > Session Management). That determines where a user is sent after login (home page or the page he requested)

Comment: @KoenLostrie Thanks understanding "deep linking" is good for me to know about.  Unfortunately when the social login authentication is initiated from a button link with the request attribute the button target overrides the deep link behaviour.  
If its possible to somehow set the request APEX_AUTHENTICATION=FACEBOOK on page submit or elsewhere then I might be able to use this.  I'll have to do some research my first attempts at this haven't worked.

Comment: You could put a comment on Dimitri's blog ?

Comment: @KoenLostrie Good idea I've done that.